# Get a list of indexes of selected DataGridViewRows

Tags: vb.net, list, datagridview

What I have currently:

```
Dim SelectedIndexList As New List(Of Integer)
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvItemList.SelectedRows
    SelectedIndexList.Add(row.Index)
Next
```

Is it possible to use LINQ (or something) to do this with less code?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible

```vb
dgvItemList.SelectedRows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)().
                         Select(function(row) row.Index).
                         ToList()
```

But your `foreach` code is more readable and faster then `LINQ` in this case

Comment: I didn't think of the necessity of the `Cast` call. Good catch.

Comment: It is necessary, because you cannot use `LINQ` with `DataGridVIewRowCollection`.  You need to cast collection to the `IEnumerable(Of DataGridViewRow)` before using `LINQ`

Answer (score 0):

you can install Resharper, https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/
 and let it convert it to LINQ automatically, buy right clicking on the query and choosing convert to LINQ

it will give you similar  results to the other answers , but the tool can be reused to other similar situations